# Get form that is inside of multiples div, when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm new using Jquery.

I'm trying get Objects that are part of a form when i press a button.

My problem is that i have multiples forms with the same class "formulario"and when I press the button Jquery give me all forms that has the same type class and I just want the forms where the button was pressed.

I have something like this:

```
<div class ="card">
     <div class = "card-header">
          First Form
    </div>

    <div class= "card-body">
         <form class="formulario">
               <label>Input one</label>
               <input type text= "text"></input>

               <label>Input Two</label>
               <input type text= "text"></input>
         <form/>

         <button class= "btn">Press</button>
    <div/>
</div>



<div class ="card">
     <div class = "card-header">
          Second Form
    </div>

    <div class= "card-body">
         <form class="formulario">
               <label>Input one</label>
               <input type text= "text"></input>

               <label>Input Two</label>
               <input type text= "text"></input>
         <form/>

         <button class= "btn">Press</button>
    <div/>
</div>
```

I tried using Jquery with something like this:

```
$('.btn').on("click", function () {
   $(this).parents().find('.formulario');
});
```

it give me all the forms that have the class "formulario", but I just want the form where the button was pressed.

In other words, I just want to look for the parents where the button is, I don't want to look in all html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the nearest formulario class you can use `.closeset`.

```
$('.btn').on("click", function () {
   $(this).closeset().find('.formulario');
});
```

Comment: i have tried of that form but this one give only the button attributes @shihab

Comment: you could also try ```.next```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you include the button inside the form tag and add the attribute `type=submit` to it it will trigger the `onsubmit` method from the current form. There you can take action based on that method and semantically that should be the correct way.

I guess the `closest` method from JQuery also might work, but it should be easier to do it with HTML5 form way.